# How to assign a method to a Func instead of a lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'd like to assign a function to the `OnTicketReceived` property of the `OAuthEvents` object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.oauthevents)

It is a `Func<TicketReceivedContext, Task>`

```
public class MyClass
{
   public void Config()
   {
      var o = new OAuthEvents
      {
         OnTicketReceived = MyFunc;  //Doesn't work
      };
   }

   public Task MyFunc(TicketReceivedContext ctx)
   {
      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

I know I can write an anonymous method using a lambda but I don't want to do that because I wish to reuse the method in multiple places. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a good problem description. What exactly happens? Do you get compilation error, runtime exception, result is different from what you expect it should be?

Comment: This code should work. Please list the exact error you are seeing in Visual Studio.

Comment: In the code you posted there is a semicolon `;` after the assignment to `OnTicketReceived`, that is not correct. If that is in your actual code, either remove it, or optionally replace it with a comma.

Comment: Yes, you are right Peter. The problem was just the semicolon after the assignment. Thank you!